# Garmin Etrex 10

Tags: geocaching, navigation, gps

I just got an etrex 10, and I am using it mostly for geocaching. When you are navigating to a geocache is there a way to see your distance from the cache? I know the geocaching app has this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your GPS device can tell you the distance to a location.  You will first need to load the cache locations onto it.  Both the manual and the quickstart guide that came with it have information on how to go about this.

You can also manually enter cache coordinates as a new waypoint.  When doing so, be careful that the coordinate formats match, e.g. if your cache is located at `N 33° 20.134' W 86° 47.037'` do not enter it as `33.20134 86.47037`.  Check your manual if you're unsure how to change the format your device is currently using.

Once stored as waypoints you can then select one to navigate to.  Your device should then tell you the approximate direction to head and the distance, as well as any other details depending on how you've customized the display.

*Side note:  You can also get a rough estimate by comparing your current coordinates to the cache coordinates, but this is particularly tedious when coordinates are in degree-based formats.*

Comment: Yup, I have an etrex 30, and it gives you a metres distance to go.